# Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details

Tags: android, unity, google-play-services

I get following error while building to Android with Unty 5.2.2f1 (with a new&clean project).

**Notes:** I use GPGS 0.9.27 and Soomla Core 1.2.1 and Profile 2.2.1 and maximum supported Facebook package for soomla profile.

```
Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details.
E:\Programlar\Android SDK Tools\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "E:/Programlar/Android SDK Tools\platforms\android-22\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages android.support.v7.appcompat:com.facebook.android:com.google.example.games.mainlibproj:com.google.android.gms.base:com.google.android.gms:com.google.android.gms.drive:com.google.android.gms.games:com.google.android.gms.nearby:com.google.android.gms.plus:com.soomla.SoomlaApp:android.support.v4 -S "F:\Test\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.1.1\res" -S "F:\Test\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res" -S "F:\Test\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-8.3.0\res" -S "F:\Test\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-basement-8.3.0\res" -S "F:\Test\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-drive-8.3.0\res" -S "F:\Test\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-games-8.3.0\res" -S "F:\Test\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-nearby-8.3.0\res" -S "F:\Test\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-plus-8.3.0\res" -S "F:\Test\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-v4-23.1.1\res"

stderr[
F:\Test\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res\drawable-hdpi\com_facebook_button_like_background.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
F:\Test\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res\drawable\com_facebook_button_like_background.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
F:\Test\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res\drawable-xhdpi\com_facebook_button_like_background.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
F:\Test\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res\drawable-xxhdpi\com_facebook_button_like_background.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
F:\Test\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res\drawable\com_facebook_button_like_background_selected.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
F:\Test\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res\drawable-hdpi\com_facebook_button_like_background_selected.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
F:\Test\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res\drawable-xhdpi\com_facebook_button_like_background_selected.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
F:\Test\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res\drawable-xxhdpi\com_facebook_button_like_background_selected.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
F:\Test\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res\drawable\com_facebook_button_like_icon.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
F:\Test\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res\drawable-hdpi\com_facebook_button_like_icon.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
F:\Test\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res\drawable-xhdpi\com_facebook_button_like_icon.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
F:\Test\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res\drawable-xxhdpi\com_facebook_button_like_icon.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
F:\Test\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res\drawable\com_facebook_button_like_icon_selected.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
F:\Test\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res\drawable-hdpi\com_facebook_button_like_icon_selected.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
F:\Test\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res\drawable-xhdpi\com_facebook_button_like_icon_selected.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
F:\Test\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res\drawable-xxhdpi\com_facebook_button_like_icon_selected.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
F:\Test\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res\drawable\com_facebook_close.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
F:\Test\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res\drawable-ldpi\com_facebook_close.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
F:\Test\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res\drawable-hdpi\com_facebook_close.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
F:\Test\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res\drawable-xhdpi\com_facebook_close.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
F:\Test\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.1.1\res\values-v23\values-v23.xml:5: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.

F:\Test\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.1.1\res\values-v23\values-v23.xml:30: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.

]
stdout[
Configurations:
 (default)

Files:
  AndroidManifest.xml
    Src: () AndroidManifest.xml

Resource Dirs:
Including resources from package: E:\Programlar\Android SDK Tools\platforms\android-22\android.jar
applyFileOverlay for drawable
trying overlaySet Key=ic_plusone_medium_off_client.png
trying overlaySet Key=ic_plusone_small_off_client.png
trying overlaySet Key=ic_plusone_standard_off_client.png
trying overlaySet Key=ic_plusone_tall_off_client.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_full_open_on_phone.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_ic_googleplayservices.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_disabled.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_focused.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_pressed.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_disabled.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_focused.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_pressed.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_disabled.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_focused.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_pressed.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light_disabled.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light_focused.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light_pressed.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_dark_disabled.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_dark_focused.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_dark_pressed.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_light.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_light_disabled.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_light_focused.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_light_normal.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_light_pressed.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_text_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_text_dark_disabled.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_text_dark_focused.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_text_dark_normal.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_text_dark_pressed.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_text_light.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_text_light_disabled.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_text_light_focused.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_text_light_normal.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_text_light_pressed.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_button_blue.xml
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_button_blue_focused.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_button_blue_normal.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_button_blue_pressed.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_button_check.xml
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_button_check_off.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_button_check_on.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_button_grey_focused.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_button_grey_normal.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_button_grey_pressed.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_button_like.xml
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_button_like_background.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_button_like_background_selected.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_button_like_icon.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_button_like_icon_selected.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_button_like_pressed.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_button_like_selected.xml
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_close.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_inverse_icon.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_list_divider.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_list_section_header_background.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_loginbutton_silver.xml
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_logo.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_picker_item_background.xml
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_picker_list_focused.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_picker_list_longpressed.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_picker_list_pressed.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_picker_list_selector.xml
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_picker_list_selector_background_transition.xml
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_picker_list_selector_disabled.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_picker_magnifier.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_picker_top_button.xml
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_place_default_icon.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_profile_default_icon.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_profile_picture_blank_portrait.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_profile_picture_blank_square.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_tooltip_black_background.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_tooltip_black_bottomnub.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_tooltip_black_topnub.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_tooltip_black_xout.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_tooltip_blue_background.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_tooltip_blue_bottomnub.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_tooltip_blue_topnub.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_tooltip_blue_xout.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_top_background.xml
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_top_button.xml
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_usersettingsfragment_background_gradient.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_action_bar_item_background_material.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_btn_borderless_material.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_btn_check_material.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_000.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_015.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_btn_colored_material.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_btn_default_mtrl_shape.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_btn_radio_material.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_btn_radio_to_on_mtrl_000.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_btn_radio_to_on_mtrl_015.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_btn_rating_star_off_mtrl_alpha.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_btn_rating_star_on_mtrl_alpha.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00001.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_cab_background_internal_bg.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_cab_background_top_material.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_cab_background_top_mtrl_alpha.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_control_background_material.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_dialog_material_background_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_dialog_material_background_light.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_edit_text_material.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_ic_clear_mtrl_alpha.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_ic_commit_search_api_mtrl_alpha.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_ic_go_search_api_mtrl_alpha.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_ic_menu_copy_mtrl_am_alpha.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_ic_menu_cut_mtrl_alpha.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_ic_menu_moreoverflow_mtrl_alpha.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_ic_menu_paste_mtrl_am_alpha.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_ic_menu_selectall_mtrl_alpha.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_ic_voice_search_api_mtrl_alpha.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_item_background_holo_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_item_background_holo_light.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_list_divider_mtrl_alpha.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_list_focused_holo.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_list_longpressed_holo.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_list_pressed_holo_dark.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_list_pressed_holo_light.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_list_selector_background_transition_holo_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_list_selector_background_transition_holo_light.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_list_selector_holo_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_list_selector_holo_light.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_popup_background_mtrl_mult.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_ratingbar_full_material.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_scrubber_control_off_mtrl_alpha.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_scrubber_control_to_pressed_mtrl_000.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_scrubber_control_to_pressed_mtrl_005.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_scrubber_primary_mtrl_alpha.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_scrubber_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_seekbar_thumb_material.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_seekbar_track_material.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_spinner_textfield_background_material.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_switch_thumb_material.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_switch_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_tab_indicator_material.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_tab_indicator_mtrl_alpha.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_text_cursor_material.xml
trying overlaySet Key=abc_textfield_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=abc_textfield_search_material.xml
trying overlaySet Key=app_banner.png
trying overlaySet Key=app_icon.png
applyFileOverlay for layout
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_friendpickerfragment.xml
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_login_activity_layout.xml
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_picker_activity_circle_row.xml
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_picker_checkbox.xml
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_picker_image.xml
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_picker_list_row.xml
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_picker_list_section_header.xml
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_picker_search_box.xml
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_picker_title_bar<message truncated>
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this error by going to **SDK Manager** and downloading **latest API** (it is  Android 6.0 - API 23 while i'm writing this).

**Note:** *You don't have to download documentation or samples if you don't need, because they two take a while to download.*

Also make sure that you have **latest versions** of "**Extras/Android Support Repository**" and "**Extras/Google Repository**".

Answer (score 1):

I have deleted the 24.0.0 build tools folder from `Android\sdk\build-tools` and it worked amazingly ..

Answer (score 0):

deleting plugins / android / google-play-services_lib / res / values / common_attrs removed this error..

source:
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/failed-to-re-package-resources-help.345837/